# What are the ways to skip the use of && in for condition statement?

Tags: c, logical-operators

There was a exercise in my book, which asked me to write a for loop equivalent to :

```
for(i=0;(i<4) && (i<5);i++)
```

but without using `&&` and `||` operator.

I came up with a solution like this :

```
for (i=0;;i++)
        if((i<4))
            if((i<5))
                printf("Works!!!\n");
            else
                break;
        else
            break;
```

It works. Since I'm a beginner in C, I want to know whether there are any better solution than this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing the simple one: `for(i=0; i<4; i++)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `&&` is combining two conditions such that one is a logically weaker one with respect to the other. If an integer is less than 4 it is necessarily less than 5. Thus `(i<4) && (i<5)` can just be replaced with `(i<4)`.

Answer (score 0):

A note on style: It is a good idea to always use braces with nested ifs, at least for the outer ones, especially with missing elses. This won't do what you've intended it to do:

```
if (Cond1)
    if (Cond2)
        DoSomething;
else
    DoSomethingElse;
```

The compiler sees the else as belonging to Cond2. This doesn't leave any room for misinterpretation:

```
if (Cond1)
{
    if (Cond2)
    {
        DoSomething;
    }
}
else
{
    DoSomethingElse;
}
```

Comment: Even your editor (if it's any good, like Vim) will see that this is wrong; when you highlight the block and reindent, it will fix the indentation to show you the real meaning.

Comment: I don't agree with adding all this vertical clutter for simple code. if (cond) { if (cond2) DoSomething; } else { DoSomethingElse; }.  If one clause needs bracing, it's usually nice to brace the other one also. If they are both one-expression jobs, leave the bracing out.